# Next image link loop

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to get my next images in a loop so they go back to the start of the the image list. I am able to get the images to go through the list right up to the last image then my last image shows no PID on the link.

I have

```
 <div id="photolistholder">
 <?php if(isset($_GET['pid'])){?>
 <?php
    //Now we'll get the list of the specified users photos
    $var =$_GET['pid'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM coverphotos WHERE coverphoto_id='$var'";
    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql)or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    while($photo = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
       $user=rawfeeds_user_core::getuser($photo['coverphoto_userid']);
 ?>
    <p class="frontpage_description"><a href="profile.php?username=<?php echo $user['username']; ?>">
 <?php 
    $id=$_SESSION['id'];
    if($user['id']){
       echo "<img border=\"0\" src=\"userimages/cropped".$user['id'].".jpg\" onerror='this.src=\"img/no_profile_img.jpeg\"' width=\"40\" ><br/>".$user['fullname']."'s</a> Album: </p>";
    }else{
       echo "<img border=\"0\" src=\"userimages/cropped".$id.".jpg\" onerror='this.src=\"img/no_profile_img.jpeg\"' width=\"40\" ><br/>".$user['fullname']." </a></p>";
    }

    $id=$_SESSION['id'];

    $var = $_GET['pid'] ;
    $photo_sql = "SELECT coverphoto_id FROM coverphotos WHERE (coverphoto_id < ".$var." OR coverphoto_id > ".$var.") AND coverphoto_userid = ".$user['id']." ORDER BY coverphoto_id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $photo_query = mysqli_query($mysqli,$photo_sql)or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    $photo_prev=mysqli_fetch_array($photo_query);

    if($photo_prev>1){
        echo"<a href='coverimagephoto.php?pid=".$photo_prev['coverphoto_id']."'>Previous</a> | ";
    }else{
        echo " ";
    }


    $var = $_GET['pid'] ;   
    $photo_sqls = "SELECT coverphoto_id FROM coverphotos WHERE (coverphoto_id > ".$var." OR coverphoto_id < ".$var.") AND coverphoto_userid = ".$user['id']." ORDER BY coverphoto_id ASC LIMIT 1";
    $photo_querys = mysqli_query($mysqli,$photo_sqls)or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
                    $photo_next=mysqli_fetch_array($photo_querys);

    if($photo_next>1){
       echo "<a href='coverimagephoto.php?pid=".$photo_next['coverphoto_id']."'>Next</a>";  
    }else{
       echo "";
    }

    $user1_id=@$_SESSION['id'];
    $user2_id=$user['id'];
    if($user1_id==@$_SESSION['id']){ 
       echo " | <a href='include/photo_delete.php?pid=".$photo['coverphoto_id']."'>Delete</a>";
    }else{
       echo"";
    }
 ?>
    <center>
 <?php
        //echo "<div class='photo_captionholder'><b>Name</b> : ".$photo['photo_name']." | <b>Caption</b> : ".$photo['photo_caption']." |                
        //<b>Uploaded</b> : ".$photo['photo_datetime']."</div>";
    echo "<img id=\"coverimage\" border=\"0\" src='coverimages/".$photo['coverphoto']."?".time()."' onerror='this.src=\"coverimages/nocover.png\"'>";

    }}
 ?>
        </body>
```

I tried using

```
$var = $_GET['pid'] ;
    $photo_sql = "SELECT coverphoto_id FROM coverphotos WHERE (coverphoto_id > ".$var." OR coverphoto_id < ".$var.") AND coverphoto_userid = ".$user['id']."";
    $photo_query = mysqli_query($mysqli,$photo_sql)or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    $photo_next=mysqli_fetch_array($photo_query);

    if($photo_next>1){
        echo"<a href='coverimagephoto.php?pid=".$photo_prev['coverphoto_id']."'>Next</a> | ";
    }else{
            echo " ";
    }
```

But the link just jumps between two images. The images are not in 1,2,3,4,5 they can be 1,2,4,5 if a user deletes an image and it can start on image PID 3 or 5.

Comment: You are not maintaining the value of `$var` surley you need to set `$var` to the current `$photo_prev['coverphoto_id']` somewhere

Comment: Isn't that done in my select? @RiggsFolly

Comment: Nothing gets done by magic, unless your name happens to be magic! I dont even see where you set $var to any value.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add `$var = $_GET['pid'];` it gets it through the url, it is in my script. I will add it to the question code now.

Comment: I assume you are in some sort of loop, maybe you could show all the relevant code rather than a snippet

Comment: Would it not be much simpler to code and reduce your queries from N+1 to 1 where N=number of photos if you just used the first query and then fetched all the results into an array, and then process up and down that array???

Comment: could you mock up an example by any chance @RiggsFolly to explain what you mean. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it not be much simpler to code and understand and also reduce your queries (round trips to the server and back) from N+1 queries to 1 query where N=(number of photos) if you just used the first query and then fetched all the results into an array, and then process up and down that array

Quick mockup:

```
<div id="photolistholder">
<?php 
   if( isset($_GET['pid']) ) {

       // validate the pid
       $_GET['pid'] = some_validation_please($_GET['pid']);
       $id=$_SESSION['id'];

       $sql = "SELECT * FROM coverphotos WHERE coverphoto_id='$_GET['pid']'";

       $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

       $photos = array();

       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
          $photos[] = $row;
       }

       foreach( $photos as $idx => $photo ) {

          // add all your image html with the prev and next links
          // using $idx-1 for prev image
          // using $idx+1 for next image
          // and checking if $idx = 0 for first image 
          //   so you can use count($photos)-1 to know you are on last image
          //   so you use photos[0] as the next image to get continuous loop
          // and if $idx == 0 next image is count($photos)-1

       }
 ?>
```

Sorry I have not got the time to pick the bones out of what you are putting out to the browser, as I am bound to make a silly mistake and get hassled for it.

Comment: Thank you. that's a great help. Just what I was after. :D

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a better way that works perfectly. Just use a UNION

```
$var = mysqli_escape_string($_GET['pid']) ;
$photo_sql = "(SELECT coverphoto_id FROM coverphotos WHERE  coverphoto_id < ".$var."  AND coverphoto_userid = ".$user['id']." AND album=1 ORDER BY coverphoto_id DESC LIMIT 1)";
$photo_sql.= " UNION (SELECT coverphoto_id FROM coverphotos WHERE  coverphoto_id > ".$var."  AND coverphoto_userid = ".$user['id']." AND album=1 ORDER BY coverphoto_id DESC LIMIT 1)";
$photo_query = mysqli_query($mysqli,$photo_sql)or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
$photo_prev=mysqli_fetch_array($photo_query);

if($photo_prev>1){
    echo"<a href='coverimagephoto.php?pid=".$photo_prev['coverphoto_id']."'>Previous</a> | ";
}else{
        echo " ";
}



$var = $_GET['pid'] ;   
$photo_sqls = "(SELECT coverphoto_id FROM coverphotos WHERE  coverphoto_id > ".$var." AND coverphoto_userid = ".$user['id']." AND album=1 ORDER BY coverphoto_id ASC LIMIT 1)";
$photo_sqls.= " UNION (SELECT coverphoto_id FROM coverphotos WHERE  coverphoto_id < ".$var."  AND coverphoto_userid = ".$user['id']." AND album=1 ORDER BY coverphoto_id ASC LIMIT 1)";
$photo_querys = mysqli_query($mysqli,$photo_sqls)or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
                $photo_next=mysqli_fetch_array($photo_querys);

if($photo_next>1){
echo "<a href='coverimagephoto.php?pid=".$photo_next['coverphoto_id']."'>Next</a>"; 
}else{
        echo " ";
}
```